# How to access a value in a RECORD which in a TABLE of TYPE TABLE Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    TYPE a_rec IS RECORD (
        name   VARCHAR2(100),
        adress VARCHAR2(100)
    );
TYPE A_DET IS TABLE OF A_REC;
TYPE A IS TABLE OF
a_det;

BEGIN
    FOR i IN a.first..a.last LOOP
        FOR j IN a_det.first..a_det.last LOOP    
          dbms_output.put_line(a(i).a_det(j).name);
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only declared the types, you have not declared a variable of any of those types. Once you do that then you can use `FOR i IN 1 .. variable_name.COUNT LOOP` to iterate over the (non-sparse) elements of the collection and use `variable_name(i)` to access the collection element and `variable_name(i)(j)` for nested collections:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE a_rec IS RECORD (
    name    VARCHAR2(100),
    address VARCHAR2(100)
  );
  TYPE A_DET IS TABLE OF A_REC;
  TYPE A IS TABLE OF a_det;
  v_a A := a(
           a_det(
             a_rec('Alice', 'AAA'),
             a_rec('Betty', 'BBB'),
             a_rec('Carol', 'CCC')
           ),
           a_det(
             a_rec('Debra', 'DDD')
           ),
           a_det(),
           a_det(
             a_rec('Emily', 'EEE'),
             a_rec('Fiona', 'FFF')
           )
         );
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_a.COUNT LOOP
    FOR j IN 1 .. v_a(i).COUNT LOOP    
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_a(i)(j).name);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
Alice
Betty
Carol
Debra
Emily
Fiona
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CqXo1Wty)

Comment: Merci beaucoup, Thank you